# Can't seem to get JQuery's .on() working for elements created through scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a system that generates multiple address fields according the an amount selected by the user.

Initially I used `$("input[name=inputname]")` which works fine for the initially loaded fiedls but doesn't work when adding more. Searching google and here led me to believe I could use JQuery's `.on` function, although I can't seem to get it working, is there anything wrong with this code or do I need to approach this a different way?

```
$("div.data").on( "change", "input[name^=delivery-address-1]", function() {
  alert( $( this ).val() );
});
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Hi, regarding the 'marked as duplicate', as I said I have read the similar answers and am aware of them, but the code learned from these answers doesn't seem to work in my situation and so was looking for further help, thanks.

Comment: which version of jquery used?

Comment: Is that the name of the new elements? `name^=delivery-address-1` Is it inside the div?

Comment: The input elements need to be inside the `<div>` Works here http://jsfiddle.net/v4AYb/

Comment: Also note that your code only works if those `<input>` elements are added inside that `<div class=data>` ...

Comment: I reopened it since whoever closed it did not read the question.

Comment: You need to show some more context, the code should work. There is something wrong with either the placement or the names of the new elements.

Comment: @TamilSelvan JQuery 1.11
@epascarello The name of generated elements are `delivery-address-1?x` where x is incremented
@ShaunakD They are
@Pointy They are

thanks for the quick responses

Comment: Just a note, the `change` event only fires for `<input>` elements when the user deselects the box. The `input` event fires after the text inside the element changes.

Comment: can you show the rendered HTML?

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/JkfSP/ So what is different?

Comment: Problem was div.data is also dynamically created, as queried by @epascarello. Again thanks everyones for quick and continued responses. Apologies for my amateurness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `document` and not `'div.data'` like so:

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name^=delivery-address-1]", function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Hehe, the same answer, 43 seconds faster. I spent too much time typing the explanation I guess :D Good answer.

Comment: This makes it works, thanks (even though it is located in div.data - `<div class="data fl"><input type="text" name="delivery-address-1?0" class="jqs-deli" /></div>`, and thanks to @Dampe aswell and everyone else for there comments!

Comment: Ugh, it is, silly me. Always simple things I overlook!

Comment: So the solution would be to put the event to where you are appending, not on the document.

Comment: Yes that's correct and I've done that now, although document still works just not preferred as you pointed out. So unless someone wants to point that out in a new answer I'll keep this checked as best.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience (and not just mine), it's often better to handle events of dynamic elements at global level. Meaning you will attach the event handler to document and use the selector filter to fire it only for matching elements.

eg:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name^=delivery-address-1]', function(){
  alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance) `For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents.`

Comment: Define 'excessive'. Fair point however. You really don't want to do this for everything.